# How can I read value from a json file and use it in the MATLAB plot function?

Tags: json, matlab

I would like to read a value from JSON file and use these values in the plot function.
So I did some research and realized that there is a lib named "loadjson" and I've added into my MATLAB. But I can't read values from my JSON file and cannot find a solution in MATLAB answers for it.
I'm kinda new at MATLAB and I need a bit of help :)

Thanks in advance.

Code:

```
% Setting my image and related params
  img = imread('C:/plan/plan.jpg');
  imshow(img)
  min_x = 0;
  max_x = 7;
  min_y = 0;
  max_y = 3;
  imagesc([min_x max_x], [min_y max_y], img);
  % Load json file
  data = loadjson('C:/data/default.json');
  disp(data)
  % I want to use these values into plot function.
  hold on;
  plot(x, y, 'ro', 'MarkerSize', 5);
```

Output of the code:

[image: Output of the code]

My JSON file:

```
"Location": [
    {
      "id": "0b5965e5-c509-4522-a525-8ef5a49dadaf",
      "measureId": "5a6e9b79-dbb1-4482-acc1-d538f68ef01f",
      "locationX": 0.9039769252518151,
      "locationY": 0.2640594070404616,
      "createdAt": "06-01-2021 19:38:44"
    },
    {
      "id": "18714a2f-a8b3-4dc6-8a5b-114497fa9671",
      "measureId": "671f52bc-a066-494a-9dce-6e9ccfac6c1d",
      "locationX": 1.5592001730078755,
      "locationY": 0.5207689756815629,
      "createdAt": "06-01-2021 19:35:24"
    },
```

Comment: Don't call you script "path" that is a matlab reserved word and you are overwritting it. You can also see that `data` contains 2 variables, each a cell array. Inspect those values, see if the information you want is there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the JSON structure, I expect each element in your `Location` cell arrays to be a struct, with at least the fields `locationX` and `locationY`.

You can extract those fields with something like

```
x = cellfun( @(cellElem) cellElem.locationX, data.Location );
y = cellfun( @(cellElem) cellElem.locationY, data.Location );
```

Comment: It worked like a charm! Thank you good sir. I've also one question. How I sort the data order by (asc) "createdAt" column?

Comment: Do the same thing for that property, but use `datetime` to convert your strings into times, remembering to specifying the format of your date string. Then you can put them all in a table and use `sortrows` or use the 2nd output of `sort` to do things manually. If this is unclear then please ask another question for this specific task.

Comment: [~,X] = sort(cellfun(@(cellElem) cellElem.createdAt, data.Location,'UniformOutput',false));

Comment: I've tried this but it did not work out. Actually I did in MATLAB Answers. 
https://ch.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/714098-sort-depends-on-value-with-cellfun?s_tid=srchtitle

Comment: As I say, you will have to use `datetime` to covert it, sorting a string doesn't make sense here. Try to do one less thing with your `cellfun` and just output a cell of strings without sorting, then you can do the conversion. If you don't understand that then please ask a new question relating to converting the cell array to datetimes and sorting

Comment: Thanks for the guidance sir, I've created a new question in here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65673147/sort-json-by-values-in-matlab